# Welcome aboard ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, ruby-on-rails-3.1, mysql2

I'm using Ubuntu, with Rails 3.0.1 with mysql2 socket.

When i do runing install, rake db:create and after rails server, my Welcome aboard, shows `ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished` in About your application’s environment

What i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like your MySQL server isn't running. You'll need to install MySQL if you haven't already (`apt-get install mysql-server` should do it). Once it's running, you'll need to set up a user and database for your app, and note the username and password so that you can put that information in `config/database.yml` within your app.

[This](http://wiki.rubyonrails.org/database-support/mysql) link will be useful if you need any help with those steps.

Answer (score 3):

Had the same problem on rails 3.1.1:
`rake db:create` - ok
`rails console` and some DMLs - ok
but accessing info from the web-page resulted in `ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished`.
A rails server restart helped.

Comment: did you do anything besides restart?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to do some more debugging to work it out.
How are you running your server?

Make yourself a model.
`rails generate model Something name:string`

Then try running `rake db:migrate`

Does this work?

If it does, then you must be running your server in a different way (maybe you're running it in production mode?)

Try `rails console` and try to do `Something.count`

If all of those work
then I'd suggest you try restarting your server.

`rails server`